# Sample autocorrelation function from multiple realisations of a stochastic processs using the convolution theorem

Tags: convolution, fourier-transform, estimation, correlation, time-series

Consider a wide-sense stationary stochastic process $X(t)$ with constant mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. The (auto)correlation function $\rho(\tau)$ of $X(t)$ is [defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Definitions):

$$\rho(\tau) = \frac{\mathbb{E}[(X(t)-\mu)(X(t+\tau)-\mu)]}{\sigma^2}$$

My question relates to the estimation of the correlation function from a discretised realisation $\boldsymbol{X} = \{X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n\}$ of $X(t)$. A simple [estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Estimation) $\hat{\rho}(\tau)$ is to compute Pearson's correlation coefficient for all pairs of lags separated by $k$:

\begin{equation}
 \hat{\rho}(k)=\frac{1}{(n-k) \sigma^2} \sum_{t=1}^{n-k} (X_t-\mu)(X_{t+k}-\mu)
\end{equation}

Now suppose that instead of a single realisation of $X(t)$ being available there are $m$ realisations of $X(t)$ available. The estimator is easily extended to this case by considering all discretised points seperated by lag $k$ for all realisations:

\begin{equation}
 \hat{\rho}(k)=\frac{1}{j(n-k) \sigma^2} \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{t=1}^{n-k} (X_{t}^j-\mu)(X_{t+k}^j-\mu)
 \end{equation}

However these estimators are computationally inefficient in comparison to an  approach depending on the [signal processing definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Signal_processing) of autocorrelation as the convolution of the signal with itself:

$$\rho(\tau) = X(t) * \bar{X}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty X(t)X(t-\tau)\, {\rm d}t$$

It is then possible to use the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) to write:

$$X(t) * \overline{{X}(t)} = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\big\{\mathcal{F}\{X(t)\}\cdot\overline{\mathcal{F}\{X(t)\}}\big\}$$

Where $\mathcal{F}\{X(t)\}$ is the Fourier transform of $X(t)$ and $\overline{\mathcal{F}\{X(t)\}}$ is its complex conjugate. This leads to a computationally efficient estimator for $\rho(\tau)$ that makes use of optimised fast Fourier transform algorithms:

\begin{equation}
 \hat{\rho}(k) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\big\{\mathcal{F}\{\boldsymbol{X}\}\cdot\overline{\mathcal{F}\{\boldsymbol{X}\}}\big\}
\end{equation}

Where $\boldsymbol{X}$ is a discretised *single* realisation of $X(t)$ (as above). My question is whether it possible to extend this approach to the case where there are $m$ realisations of $X(t)$? Say that $\boldsymbol{X}$ is an $n$ by $m$ matrix instead of a vector.

Comment: If $ \mathbb{E}[X_t]$ and $R_k = \mathbb{E}[(X_t-\mu)( X_{t+k}-\mu)]$ is constant then $R_k =\lim_{A \to \infty} \frac{1}{2A} \mathbb{E}[\int_{-A}^A (X_t-\mu)( X_{t+k}-\mu)dt] = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{2N} \mathbb{E}[\sum_{n=-N}^N (X_n-\mu)(X_{n+k}- \mu)]=\frac{1}{2N} \sum_{n=-N}^N \mathbb{E}[(X_n-\mu)(X_{n+k}- \mu)]$.

Comment: For this last one, a good estimator is $\widehat{R}_k=\frac{1}{2N m}\sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{n=-N}^N (x_n^{(j)}-\mu)(x_{n+k}^{(j)}- \mu)$ where $x^{(j)},j=1 \ldots m$ are realizations of your process. You can compute $\widehat{R}_k$ (for $k = 1 \ldots K$) efficiently from the FFT of $\frac{1}{m} \sum_{j=1}^m x^{(j)}_n-\mu, n = -N \ldots N-K$

Comment: Did you get what I wrote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the DFT is a Linear Operator you can apply the averaging in the Fourier Domain and have the same result as in the time domain.

In practice, just pay attention that DFT which is what used applies Circular Convolution.
You either will be OK with that or pad your signals accordingly.